# kafka consumer try to connect to random hostname instead right one

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka and started exploring with sample program. It used to work without any issue but all of sudden consumer.poll() command hangs and never returns. Googling suggested to check the servers are accessible. Producer and Consumer java code runs in same machine, where producer able to post record to Kafka, but consumer poll method hangs.

**Environment:**
Kafka version: 1.1.0
Client: Java
Runs in Ubuntu docker container inside windows
Zookeeper and 2 Broker servers runs in same container

When I have enabled logging for client code, I see below exception:

```
2018-07-06 21:24:18 DEBUG NetworkClient:802 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=IDCS_Audit_Event_Consumer] Error connecting to node 4bdce773eb74:9095 (id: 2 rack: null)
java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: 4bdce773eb74:9095
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:235)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:214)
    .................
    .................
```

I'm not sure why consumer trying to connect to `4bdce773eb74` even though my broker servers are `192.168.99.100:9094,192.168.99.100:9095`. And my full consumer code:

```
        final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "192.168.99.100:9094,192.168.99.100:9095";
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "Event_Consumer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());

        KafkaConsumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<Long, String>(props);
        TopicPartition tpLogin = new TopicPartition("login1", 0);
        TopicPartition tpLogout = new TopicPartition("logout1", 1);
        List<TopicPartition> tps = Arrays.asList(tpLogin, tpLogout);
        consumer.assign(tps);
        while (true) {
            final ConsumerRecords<Long, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(1000);
            if (consumerRecords.count()==0) {
                continue;
            }
            consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
                System.out.printf("Consumer Record:(%d, %s, %d, %d)\n", record.key(), record.value(),
                        record.partition(), record.offset());
            });

            consumer.commitAsync();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
```

Please help in this issue.

**EDIT**
As I said earlier, I have 2 brokers, say broker-1 and broker-2. If I stop broker-1, then above exception is not logged, but still `poll()` method didn't returns.
Below message logged indefinitely, if I stop broker-1:

```
2018-07-07 11:31:24 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:579 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=IDCS_Audit_Event_Consumer] Sending FindCoordinator request to broker 192.168.99.100:9094 (id: 1 rack: null)
2018-07-07 11:31:24 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:590 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=IDCS_Audit_Event_Consumer] Received FindCoordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1530943284196, latencyMs=2, disconnected=false, requestHeader=RequestHeader(apiKey=FIND_COORDINATOR, apiVersion=1, clientId=consumer-1, correlationId=573), responseBody=FindCoordinatorResponse(throttleTimeMs=0, errorMessage='null', error=COORDINATOR_NOT_AVAILABLE, node=:-1 (id: -1 rack: null)))
2018-07-07 11:31:24 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:613 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=IDCS_Audit_Event_Consumer] Group coordinator lookup failed: The coordinator is not available.
2018-07-07 11:31:24 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:227 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=IDCS_Audit_Event_Consumer] Coordinator discovery failed, refreshing metadata
```

Thanks in Advance,
Soman

Comment: Which version of Kafka? The latest is 1.1.0 per [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads). The 2.11 refers to the version of Scala.

Comment: @NickPredey have downloaded `kafka_2.11-1.1.0`, then I Kafka version is 1.1.0?

Comment: Yes, that is the version.

Comment: have you tried console consumer? @user

Comment: try with individual brokers @user

Comment: Try using the console consumer and following the tutorial [here](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).

Comment: @Deadpool, added information, if I try running with individual broker

Comment: props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "Event_Consumer");, groupId=IDCS_Audit_Event_Consumer]  i think both consumers are different  @user

Comment: @Deadpool Yes GroupID is different, when I was adding information later, but at that time my consumer code had the GroupID IDCS_Audit_Event_Consumer, so that doesn't seem to be issue.

Comment: According to my understanding you are trying to consume login1 topic partition 0, logout1 topic partition 1 am i right?    1) topic existed are not?     2) verify partitions of each topic?    3) if 1 and 2 are then try console consumer     4) if these three points work then something wrong in code.  use kafka tool to check topics and partitions . @user

Comment: @Deadpool I found the issue. When I'm creating topic, broker-0 and broker-2 was running. Now I have mistakenly started broker-1 and broker-2. After stopping broker-1 and starting broker-0, resolves the issue. Consumer able to get the events. Does it qualifies as a bug?

Comment: it's just a mislead in brokers @Soman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174550/discussion-between-soman-and-deadpool).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. When I'm creating topic, broker-0(runs on port:9093; broker id:0) and broker-2(runs on port:9094; broker id:2) was running. Today I have mistakenly started broker-1(runs on port:9095; broker id:1) and broker-2. After stopping broker-1 and starting broker-0, resolves the issue. Now consumer able to get the events.

Definitely human error from my side, but I have 2 comments:

1. I think Kafka should gracefully use broker-2(port no:9094) and ignore broker-1(port no:9095)
2. why Kafka trying to contact 4bdce773eb74:9095, instead of right IP address(192.168.99.100)?

thanks.